# Save Stored Procedure result in variable

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures

I've been looking for ways on how to get the result of the stored procedure I'm working on.

So when this SP is called on, it will return a series of numbers in an auto increment number. `ex. 0000002743`

I am not the one who created the SP and I'm a beginner in SQL Server but when I try to 'modify'it to at least see how it's made of, I have this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[New_BatchCode] AS
DECLARE @x NUMERIC
UPDATE SysVars SET @x = BatchCode = BatchCode + 1
SELECT BatchCode = REPLACE(STR(@x,10),' ','0')
```

In SQL Server, I just get to run `EXEC [dbo].[New_BatchCode]`and the result will be displayed. But in PHP, I can't make it work. I tried the following:

**1**

```
$conn = $this->delphi_connect();
    $batch_code_query = "EXEC [dbo].[New_BatchCode];";
    $stmt3 = sqlsrv_query($conn,$batch_code_query); 
    if( $stmt3 === false )  
    {  
         echo "Error in executing statement 3.\n";  
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));  
    }
    if ($stmt3)  {
        while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt3, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $ret[] = $row;
        }
    }
    sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt3);  
    sqlsrv_close( $conn); 
    print_r($ret);
    die();
```

**2**

```
$conn = $this->delphi_connect();
    $batch_code_query = "{call [dbo].[New_BatchCode]}";
    $stmt3 = sqlsrv_query($conn,$batch_code_query); 
    if( $stmt3 === false )  
    {  
         echo "Error in executing statement 3.\n";  
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));  
    }
    if ($stmt3)  {
        while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt3, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $ret[] = $row;
        }
    }
    sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt3);  
    sqlsrv_close( $conn); 
    print_r($ret);
    die();
```

**My SQL Server**
[image]

My goal is to somehow store the result of the executed SP and insert it on another query. Like `$batch_code = [result]`.

I'm not really sure what to do anymore. I'll be grateful for your help. Thanks!

Comment: The result of which row? when you update your table it will update all rows, so you need to check `INSERTED` table and detect if the operation is an `INSERT` or `UPDATE`, the values will be stored in a table because it's multiple values not just one.

Comment: Hi @Sami! It returns only one column called `BatchCode`. I need to get that value. I will put up the image above.

Comment: Which row of `BatchCode` column? There is no `WHERE` so it will update all rows, which mean multiple values.

Comment: @Sami apologies. I'm not sure if I'm right, but there's no where since the stored procedure only gives me a value.

Comment: The `SP` gives you a random value because there is no `WHERE` or any `ORDER`. I think the only way to do what are you trying to do is a `TRIGGER` where you can return all values inserted.

Comment: @Sami yes. That is how it should be. I just can't display the result in my PHP code.

Comment: The problem here is that you are trying to maintain your own identity or sequence values by using CurrentValue + 1. This type of approach has lots of problems with concurrency. If this value is always in the same table you should use the identity property. If it a batch number that can appear in different tables then a sequence is the right way to go. You also made a mistake in declaring your datatype. You stated numeric but did not specify the scale or precision which means it will use the default. Do you know those defaults? In your case an int seems like a much better datatype anyway.

Comment: Hi @Sean Lange, thank you for your inputs! I an new to SQL so I still have a lot to learn. Executing the SP is the first step, then I concatenate it to a specific code based on the user’s input. Is there an easier way to get the value without having to go with @Sami’s solution?

Comment: Yes, forget the notion of doing this yourself. You don't want to have a stored procedure that keeps track of an incrementing value like this. The whole approach is not a good one. I would also suggest that since you are learning you get in the habit of using a verb in your procedure names. Remember, a procedure does something. In your example simply saying GetNewBatchCode makes it a lot clearer what the procedure is doing since it tells you, where New_BatchCode leaves you wondering what it does.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by creating a [TRIGGER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql) on your table for the updates, then you can use a [#Temporal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables) table or create a table (as needed) where you can store the inserted values from the [INSERTED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables) table and do whatever you need to do with them .

Comment: I’ll try to work on your suggestion. I’m still a beginner so i really don’t have any idea on what to do. I never thought this would be complicated (in my level of knowledge).